# CSS transform scale is not working as wanted with overflow: scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In React, when I increase scale it gets hidden from the left side and also from the top. I want to show the full scale of the image from the top and left.

I want that when I scroll or increase the scale it will cover all the increased scale that image have contain.

```html
<div id="imagesection" style={{ width: "75%" }} ref={getElement}>
  <img
    src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/gamedev/uploads/legacy/043_freeShmupSprites/Free_Shmup_Sprites_Boss_Battle.jpg"
    id="image"
    ref={getElement2}
    alt=""
    className="image"
    style={{
// it's depend upon the position of cursor.
      transformOrigin: `${x}px ${y}px`,
// it's depend upon the the wheel of mouse
      transform: `scale(${universalWidth})`,
      transition: "transform 0.3s linear",
      ...styles,
    }}
  />
</div>
```

```css
#imagesection {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 12px;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 90vh;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
#image{
  width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: You are setting the transform-origin - but do you actually want it to scale from the top left corner so that that upper part of the image isn't out of the viewport?

Comment: @AHaworth yes sir the image is get hidden but i want to show full image